# Generating public private keys from openpgp

Tags: javascript, node.js, openpgp, openpgp.js

I have the following code and I'm trying to generate public-private key:

```
const openpgp = require("openpgp")
const generateKeyPair = async () => {
const { publicKeyArmored } = await openpgp.generateKey({
    userIds: [
        {
            name: 'Jon Smith', email: 'jon@example.com',
            comment: 'This key is for public sharing'
        }
    ],
    curve: 'ed25519',
    passphrase: 'super long and hard to guess secret',
});

console.log(publicKeyArmored);
}
```

But I'm getting this error. Any idea how to solve it:

```
(node:17380) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Unknown option: userIds
```

Comment: not userIds, but userIDs: https://www.npmjs.com/package/openpgp

Comment: The error is solved but the variable is undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

publicKeyArmored is not the method of openpgp.generateKey try publicKey.

```
const openpgp = require("openpgp")
const generateKeyPair = async () => {
    const { publicKey } = await openpgp.generateKey({
        curve: 'ed25519',
        userIDs: [
            {
                name: 'Jon Smith', email: 'jon@example.com',
                comment: 'This key is for public sharing'
            }
        ],
        passphrase: 'super long and hard to guess secret',
    });

    console.log(publicKey);
}

generateKeyPair()
```

output ---->
[image]